# How to assign READER role - storage.objects.get

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, terraform

Need some help on Terraform on GCP storage.

How do I assign all objects (future and current) READER role in GCP cloud storage. I need `storage.objects.get` on to be created objects?

```
resource "google_storage_object_acl" "assign_objects_reader_role_on_my_storage_bucket" {
      object = google_storage_bucket_object.objects.output_name
      bucket = my_storage_bucket.name
      role = ["READER"]
      user = "my_user"
}
```

[Example Usage - Storage Object Access Control Public Object](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_object_access_control#example-usage---storage-object-access-control-public-object) - What should be the value of `google_storage_bucket_object.object.output_name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Role - **Storage Legacy Object Reader** (**roles/storage.legacyObjectReader**)

Description - Grants permission to **view objects and their metadata**, excluding ACLs.

Permissions - **storage.objects.get**

Comment: Does this mean: `role: roles/storage.legacyObjectReader`, `permissions: storage.objects.get` ?